# Add additional argument for emit events - Quasar

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar framework.  And would like to add a 3rd argument on the framework component's preset.

---

This is for `Q-popup-edit`'s `save` / `cancel` events:

**Syntax:**

`@save` -> `function(value, initialValue)`

**Description**

Emitted when value has been successfully validated and it should be saved

**Parameters:**

`value` - Validated value to be saved

`initialValue` - Initial value, before changes

---

Is there a way so that I do not have to specify the 'new' and 'old' value and just pass in my 3rd argument?
`@save="saved(.., .., arg3)"` or something like `@cancel="canceled(arg3)"`. If that is not possible, then how can I pass the initial and new values?

```
<q-popup-edit buttons lazy-rule v-model="props.row.value" @save=(newValue, initialValue, arg3)?
```

```
...
methods: {
  saved (val, initialValue, arg3) {
    console.log(`original value = ${initialValue}, new value = ${val}`)
    console.log('argument3 = ' + arg3)
  },
  canceled (val, initialValue, arg3) {
    console.log(`retain original value = ${initialValue}, canceled value = ${val}`)  
    console.log('argument3 = ' + arg3)
  }
}
...
```

Quasar Q-popup-edit documentation:
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/popup-edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this.

example -

```
@filter="(val,update,abort) => yourFilterFn(val,update,abort,yourCustomParam)"



@save="(newValue, initialValue) => yourFilterFn(newValue,initialValue,third_argument)"
```